# Changing value of DateTimePicker programatically doesn't update GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I want to change the value of a DateTimePicker when my form opens so in the constructor I do something like:

```
timePicker.Value = new DateTime(1999, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10); //Just picking a random date and time
```

If I put a breakpoint in and look at the "Value" of timePicker it is indeed 10:10:10 AM on 5/5/1999, but in the actually GUI the DateTimePicker is just DateTime.Now.

No matter what I try the GUI shows DateTime.Now as the value for timePicker.

I tried calling Invalidate() on timePicker, thinking that it was the GUI just not updating but that didn't do anything.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: where do you run the code?

Comment: In the constructor of the form.

Comment: looks like you have some code elsewhere causing this problem because it works OK for me.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll have a look again but I remember searching the whole file for 'timePicker.Value =' to see if that was the case.

Comment: Create a ValueChanged event and put a breakpoint in it, that way you can see what's "overriding" your assignment?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the `Checked` property of the `DateTimePicker` has been set to `false`.

When the `ShowCheckBox` property of it is `false` (the default), one cannot tell whether a `DateTimePicker` is `Checked` or not, because for some reason (perhaps intentional, perhaps not), when `Checked` is false, it does not get greyed out like it does when `ShowCheckBox` is `true` (let alone the fact that there will be no checkbox shown, obviously).

On the other hand, apparently in such a case, where you set `Value` makes a difference. If you set it with the `Load` event of the form, the datetime displayed will be what `Value` has been set to, because(?) `Checked` will be changed (back) to `true` automatically, which is consistent with the behavior in which you change the datetime / `Value` from the UI.

However, if you set `Value` in the constructor of the form, `Checked` will remain unchanged, and the datetime displayed will therefore(?) not be what `Value` has been programmatically set to. (But if you check `Value` with e.g. `MessageBox.Show()`, you will see that what you set did get stored in the property.)

Comment: I had a similar problem, and this answer solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I had 2 Fields in a winForms designer:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker von;
private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker bis;
```

And I initialized the object value in constructor like this:

```
this.bis = new DateTimePicker();
```

And after that, I assigned a new value to my DateTimePicker objects:

```
von.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)userAbsenceInfos["AbsenceFrom"]);
von.Refresh();
von.Show();
von.Update(); // I feel like Tobey Maguire in Spiderman Movie
```

Apparently `new DateTimePicker()` causes the value to change once. And further changes to the DateTimePicker object in the same method are not applied to the UI.

Comment: PS
Not sure how relevant that is. I've never touched Windows Forms before -> i normally use WPF. I just got this old project and had to change some stuff there